# Android layout - display 2 vectors & text of a button

Tags: android, button, layout

I am trying to build buttons made of:
a **vector** (some sort of frame) behind a **another vector** (some sort of icon) and both above a **text** (some sort of description).

This whole object (vectors & text) should be clickable.

---

- See this *wireframe* for example (the required view):

[image]

---

Currently, I didn't manage to do this.
The only result I was able to achieve is the creation of a button that 2 vectors are starched all over it and the text is inside the frame. The visual result is different from the required:

- See this *layout* for example (the current view):

[image]

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_frame"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_settings"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_txtSettings"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btn_dri"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_fov" />
```

---

**Anyone have an idea how to create the desired button?**

Comment: If you make a drawable with the frame and the icon and put in background i thinks that should work. The other solution is make a custom view.